# How do I change my default to adobe reader?

Tags: windows-explorer, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I have Adobe Acrobat 6 and Adobe Reader 9.4 installed.
I have *Reader* set as the default for viewing downloaded files, but when on the internet (Explorer), it tries to open in *Acrobat* and it doesn't recognize that I have *Reader*.

How do I change that?

Comment: Usually when you open a PDF in a web browser, it will ask you if you want to use Adobe Reader, and then ask if you want to default it.

Comment: I inserted "Reader" and "Acrobat" into your question. I hope that's what you meant. Otherwise, please change it back.

Comment: Do you still use Adobe Acrobat 6?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat products (including Reader) are not designed to co-exist on computers. It's stupid, really, because unless you're made of money, you're likely to have an older version of "Pro" and will need Reader to operate with the latest features.

Anyway, the best way to determine which one gets precedence in opening files is to install them in the reverse order you wish them to open files.

So, if you want "Pro" to open files, install Reader first. And if you want Reader to open files, install "Pro" first.

Sometimes simply repairing the apps is enough to get them to take precedence if you've already got both of them installed.

Oh setting precedence for IE is another weird and horrific beast altogether. The above fix may work for IE, but I've found it best to set Adobe NOT to open the PDFs in the browser window so that the OS handles which one IE will open PDFs with.